# Governors' daughters and what to do with them

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

Upon sailing into the first port, I was told by a bartender that a certain city governor's daughter is very beautiful and was introduced by the governor to his plain daughter, who wanted to dance with me.

Should I save myself for the beautiful daughter or dance with every girl I see? What does dancing with them even do? Is there anything else I should be aware of when it comes to governors' daughters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All governors in the Caribbean have a daughter looking to marry, and if you play your cards right, you might be the lucky man. They give you famepoints. Daughters can be

- Plain-looking: 8 Fame points: Easy dance
- Attractive: 9 Fame points: Medium dance
- Beautiful: 10 Fame points: Hard dance

The daughters gives you a variety of gossip and items too.
They can also provide you with pieces of lost cities maps.
The items given, depends on how well you dance.

I can recommend that you decline marriage with all but Beautiful daughters, simply to get as many points as you can.

*The better you dance, the larger the heart gets in the top of the screen.*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Dancing with the governor's daughter will put you on the path of courting them in an attempt to ask them for marriage.  Though you may want to eventually marry a beautiful daughter, its worth dancing with every girl because they will often pass on rumors and quests that cross their dad's desk.

Comment: So I can, theoretically, court every governor's daughter in the game? Can I only marry one? When do I commit to a particular daughter? Do beautiful daughters have any advantages beyond their status? Can I keep dancing with other daughters after I'm married?

Comment: @kotekzot beautiful daughters give you the highest score at retirement, and I believe that plain daughters can't give you the rarer stuff like lost treasure map.  As for after marriage, I'm not sure about that part but you can court as many daughters as you want before you get married.

Comment: Once you've married one, all the other courtships will basically go into a repeat dance loop after you've given them a gift. They'll still sometimes have info for you though, I think.

Answer (score -3):

If you are playing on the PC version I discovered a "cheat". Instead of asking to dance which would take time away from plundering you can just hit the space bar to pass all of those steps. You will only be able to marry one. Each nation has it's beautiful, gorgeous or plain daughters. You will not be able to dance or marry or court everyone. Only one woman (why a pirate only chooses one I have no idea). Just hit the space button so you can keep an eye on everyone who is beautiful.

This is what happens when you hit the space bar and when to hit it:

1. Right Before you choose whether or not to accept or decline to dance hit the space bar
2. The space bar acts as an in-between option that neither annoys the daughter nor pleases her.
3. What this means is that you can just skip dancing all together
4. This does not mean that you will be courting her when you leave (It's just  a way to avoid the 8 and a half minute dancing and cut-scenes).

This works on all daughters. So if you see a real ugly daughter just hit the spacebar. The govenor won't be angry with you and you're free to go about pirating.

Comment: You can dance with and court every daughter, you just can't marry them all.

Comment: Holding space just makes me stumble.

Comment: Not during the dances when the daughter asks you to dance you hit space then.

Comment: Maybe you could describe what happens when you press the space bar?

Comment: I don't believe rejecting an invitation to a ball has any negative consequences.

Comment: @kotekzot Every time you do something good for a governor it increases the chances of gaining a rank with that nation. If you displease a governor it lowers the chance of gaining a rank.