# What happens if I dance with a governor's daughter after marrying another?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

I successfully wooed and married the daughter of the governor of Port Royale ❤️. I recently sailed into Havana and received a dance offer from the governor's daughter there. I assume I have no chance of marrying her (right?) but will my wife in Port Royale be upset that I'm cheating on her in Havana?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per the answer that says this is answered in another question.

Comment: @pppery the answer is in a comment, though. Comments on SE are ephemeral and can't be voted down, so my question isn't actually answered there.

Comment: I can just tell you from my own experience that you can romance other women, but only marry once and romancing other women will not have an impact on your wife. I did try to find a confirmed article but was only able to find posts matching what I have experienced in other online forums.

Answer (score 1):

I found another [stack thread from 2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127709/governors-daughters-and-what-to-do-with-them) that answers your question in the comments.

Once you are married you can still dance with other daughters, but will not progress any further than the dance.

*Edit: To add to what I have mentioned above, romancing other women will not impact your relationship with the woman you married. This comes from personal experience and is as well mentioned in the linked thread, but I was not able to find an official source about romancing several women in the game.*